# How to clear the Angular CLI command line after each compilation

Tags: terminal, windows-10, angular-cli, command-prompt

I'm using Angular CLI 9.0.3 on Windows 10, inside the standard Windows command prompt, to run `ng build`.

When there are errors reported in the command prompt, it can be difficult to determine how far back to scroll in order to see the first error in the current compilation.

Using MacOS it's possible to use `Command-k` to clear the terminal while it's running, but to my knowledge the Windows requires you to stop the service then use `cls` to clear the command prompt.

Is there a way to clear the terminal automatically each time the app compiles, so that I can scroll to the top of the command window to see the first error?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, except I was using [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/) instead of the standard command prompt.

I was under the assumption that while `ng build` was running, the terminal would not listen for keystrokes and therefore it would have to be an option built into the `ng cli`.  But reading your comment about it being possible in MacOS with `Command-k` gave me hope.

So, I just confirmed that in Windows Terminal there is a `clear buffer` command that is available in the Command Palette, and you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it in the settings.

Windows Terminal continues to pleasantly surprise me like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular 17 you can use `--clear-screen` when serving the application. Or you can add it to the angular.json under the build options.

[more info in Angular docs](https://angular.io/cli/build#:%7E:text=string-,%2D%2Dclear%2Dscreen,-Automatically%20clear%20the)